# How to get Sum of column with absolute value in Matrix in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssms, ssms-2014

I am new in SSRS and I am creating a report in which I need sum of column with absolute value as Gross.
I have following database structure :

```
ExpCat  long_short  Qty
USA     Long        10
USA     Long        30
USA     Long        -15
USA     Short       5 
USA     Short       -1
Japan   Long        50
Japan   Long        10
Japan   Short       -2
```

I used long_short column in row group and ExpCat colum as column group in matrix.

Current Output :

```
Entity  Japan   USA
 Long   60      25
 Short  -2      4
 Gross  58      29
```

Desired Output:

```
Entity  Japan   USA
Long    60      25
Short   -2      4
Gross   62      29
```

Here Gross is absolute sum of Long and Short respective to Japan and USA.

I am tried following expression to calculate Gross:

```
=IIf(InScope("ExpCat"),Sum(Field!Qty),0)
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure `=iff(InScope..`' is a typo, but just to make sure... Don't you want `IIF` ?

Comment: Yes that a typo, it should be IIF, I used correct syntax in my SSRS report

Answer (score 2):

I SSRS you should be able to build an expression. The expression should be something like:
    =Abs(iff(InScope("ExpCat"),Sum(Field!Qty),0))
that should give you the value you are looking for.

Comment: Expression did not work in my case, I used it. In my example Japan has Long = 60 and Short = -2 , I need output 62 for Japan but your expression is giving 58 as a output.

Comment: Maybe try doing =IIf(InScope("ExpCat")),Sum(abs(Field!Qty)),0) that may work. Just wrap whatever value is negative in abs() or your could use and IF statement to check if the value is < 0 if it is multiply it by -1.